# TemplateDoesNotExist at / templates/main/index.html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, templates

Start to learn django from guide. And get this error every time.

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/main/index.html

I read about this error from official DJango documentation, but I couldn't find enter from situation

my project

[my project's ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp4LE.png)

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-s%$#ykq62b_1q)#574(c7djut6bn66m5!i+3x&ypj*2h^k&%_f'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []




INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'taskmanager.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'main'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'taskmanager.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}




AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]




LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True




STATIC_URL = '/static/'




DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**taskmanger\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
]
```

**main\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
```

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),

```
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

Comment: Likely it is `return render(request, 'main/index.html')`: the `templates` directory are the root directories where they start searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django template engines sees the `templates/` directories of the apps as root directories, given you set [**`APP_DIRS=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates).

This thus means that you should *not* mention the `templates/` directory but work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

Comment: So it doesn't work, but i did how you said.

Comment: @Joody: what files does the `templates/main` directory contain, did you set `'APP_DIRS': True` in the `TEMPLATES` setting?

Comment: templates/main contain file index.html. And In settings 'APP_DIRS': True